# How to Uninstall / Remove Ubuntu 12.04 from Live Media

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I need to uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu, but when I open it, the only options that come up are Demo mode and Learn more, nothing about Uninstalling.

Comment: Do you mean that when you run the Ubuntu LiveCD, the only options are Try Ubuntu??? Because I don't think there are Demo mode and Learn More options. There are only two options when you run Ubuntu via LiveCD and that is Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You can uninstall Ubuntu doing a new install. During this new install, you overwrite the old install formatting the old partitions and you replace their old content with the new installation.

Of course, consider doing a backup before.

Answer (score 0):

Well Firstly there is no Option like **UNINSTALL** UBUNTU anywhere in Ubuntu universe , its **Remove**.

You can easily **Remove** your Current Ubuntu Installation by Using LiveCd or LiveUSB to Install a Fresh New Ubuntu OS.

Just follow the same steps you followed while installing your old ubuntu , just Search and Select  the **FORMAT** option To the Old Ubuntu Partition drive. And proceed to new installation on the same Partition Drive or other drives as you wish.

Thats It.

**NOTE** :  Do backup your important data from that partition , before proceeding. You can also copy your files using the Live Media of Installation. Also if you want same applications , Packages from the Old Installation , just follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/159667/63025)  before New installation.