# How do I view packages that I have installed

Tags: 12.04

I want to be able to view packages that I have installed.  I don't want it to be EVERY package on my computer but just the ones I got from ubuntu Software Center and sudo apt-get install.

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center -> installed packages

Comment: or Ubuntu software center -> History -> Installations

Comment: additionally, your question may be a possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/159664/how-to-list-user-installed-applications-not-packages

Comment: Better yet, possible duplicate of [How to list all installed packages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/17823/52726).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Ubuntu Software Center** :

Go to the *Installed* Tab:

[image]

You can also view all the software that you installed from the software  Center by going to the *History* Tab:

Answer (score 0):

#### aptitude way

By using [aptitude [image: Install aptitude]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude) you can list packages and see whether they were installed automatically (as a dependency) or manually installed:

```
aptitude search '~i!~M'
```

Unfortunately, a lot of base/system packages are installed and marked as manually installed after installation already.

Cons: lists quite some system packages marked as manually installed too.

#### apt history log

Alternatively, look at the logs APT keeps for 12 months by default in `/var/log/apt/history.log` (and rotated files). Use `grep` to filter for lines about installed packages throughout all files:

```
zgrep ^Install /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

Cons: removed packages are still listed, only has last 12 months of history by default.

Answer (score 0):

In syslog you can view too - which packages currently have been installed - in dpkg.log is listed of recent month, what has been updated or installed.