# How to find and start Thunderbird or any application in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, thunderbird

I have just transfered from Vista to Ubuntu.  I am computer-illiterate. I think Thunderbird is installed, but not sure.  How do I see if it is installed?  How do I start it? Please, no involved technical explanations, just simple steps.

Comment: Maybe you should try clicking on the icon of a letter in the top right corner of the screen then choosing Thunderbird?

Answer (score 4):

Thunderbid comes preinstalled in Ubuntu. You can find/run it in two ways:

- Graphical: Open the Dash (the top launcher in the left applications bar, with Ubuntu's symbol) and type `Thunderbird`. When it shows up, click it and Thunderbird will start.
- Command line: Open a Terminal window and run `thunderbird`. It will then start. Note that when you do it through a terminal it keeps "attached" to the terminal window, so if you close it Thunderbird will be killed.

Comment: Another way to run without the terminal window is to use Alt+F2 and type `thunderbird`

Comment: +1 just to add, after initial launch it will be able to be launched via the icon in the top bar.  A new icon will appear that looks like an envelope clicking on that will pop up(down) a menu that will allow you to launch it from that shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

To check if any program is installed, run this in a terminal:

```
apt-cache policy "software-package-name"
```

On my computer, the result is

```
thunderbird:
Installed: 1:38.5.1+build2-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
Candidate: 1:38.5.1+build2-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
```

If you prefer a GUI, you can look for a program in the Ubuntu Software Center, which will tell you if it is installed or not, and also if it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

A few things have changed in operating systems since Windows Vista or earlier versions of Ubuntu and have become common among major operating systems.

Opening the **dash** board or start menu with the Windows key <kbd>Win</kbd> let's you search for applications, files and other content, you should be able to find Thunderbird there.

New applications to install or manage software are more consumer oriented, some of them are called stores, in Ubuntu it's currently called **Software Center**. You can browse all available software in Ubuntu, look which software  is already installed, like Thunderbird, which software was updated and so on.

[image: query in software center for thunderbird in the installed applications section]

More information:

- [How to list user installed applications (not packages)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159664/40581)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-center

Taskbars and application launchers are expected to behave like [docks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Microsoft_Windows), e.g. you can pin applications to then.

- [How to add programs to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/224004/40581)