# Copy ubuntu and all files from usb drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I have a USB with Ubuntu installed on it, and I use it to boot into Ubuntu on my computer. Is there a way to use it to install Ubuntu onto my computer, so that it replaces my old operating system, and it is an exact copy of my USB Ubuntu (with all the same files and programs installed)?

Basically I want to switch from booting Ubuntu from a USB to running it full time. How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Although that's not your question, it's easier to generate a list of all installed applications on the USB and reinstall them in a fresh installation.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: [How to list user installed applications (not packages)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159664/how-to-list-user-installed-applications-not-packages)