# Ubuntu 20.04 adding to applications list from source - how to install clipgrab

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, shortcuts, appmenu

I recently installed Clipgrab application from source. According to the documentation I can run it with ./clipgrab inside the build folder in terminal. That works fine, but I would rather have it added to my applications list so I can search for it and run it without having to do it in terminal. Please don't suggest adding the PPA. I **don't** want to use the PPA because it doesn't update often enough.

I would like it to be available for all users so it doesn't need to be in `~/.local/share/applications/` so instead I tried making a `clipgrab.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` with this inside:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Clipgrab v3.8.13
Comment=Clipgrab v3.8.13
Icon=/home/alex/Downloads/clipgrab-3.8.13/icon.png
Exec=/home/alex/Downloads/clipgrab-3.8.13/clipgrab
Terminal=false
Categories=Qt;
Keywords=clip;
```

That didn't really do anything since I don't see it in my search result. **Would anyone please give me a step by step how I can add this to my list of available applications for all users?**

**Also**, I don't want to install another package to do this like in Synaptic in this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159664/how-to-list-user-installed-applications-not-packages).

I tried searching for this on here, but a lot of the instructions are outdated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually install my apps that way. You approach is correct, your desktop file should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/bin/clipgrab-3.8.13/clipgrab
Name=Clipgrab
Comment=Grabber program
Icon=/usr/local/bin/clipgrab-3.8.13/clipgrab.png 
NoDisplay=false
Categories=GTK;AudioVideo
```

Ususally (as in this example) I install the code into `/usr/local/bin`, so I don't have to mess the user path and make it acessible for all.
Since you want it for several users you should move clipgrab to the path mentioned above.

To make is accessible in a terminal you could either add that path to your profile or create a link of the executable to `/usr/bin`

Comment: that worked, but why didn't it work before when I had it in ~/Downloads ?