# User installed applications list

Tags: apt, bash, python3, appmenu

I want the list of user installed applications in linux. It should be a single list of everything user installed. More like the apps listed in "show applications". The solution can be linux commands, bash script or python (with no need of any new pip installs).

Comment: Do you mean packages list ? or each user separated installed applications in its own home directory ? Do you mean also python (pip) installed ?  other ?

Comment: @francoisP I dont need pip installed list. I mean like a list of application that we see in windows control panel "Add program" section. I want that kind in linux

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159664/how-to-list-user-installed-applications-not-packages